# Gitlab-ci.yml mysql service connection probelm

Tags: php, mysql, docker, gitlab-ci

I want to deploy my php application to aws instance, without mysql working well, but if I want to add mysql service, I can't reach to mysql service. gitlab documentation says that I can reach using mysql host name.

You can see following gitlab-ci.yml Dockerfile codes.

Gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:


IMAGE_NAME: dockerhub
  IMAGE_TAG: tagname

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_image:
  stage: build
  image: docker:20.10.16
  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
    - mariadb

  variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: pt01db
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: PASS
    MYSQL_HOST: mariadb

  before_script:
    - docker login -u username -p pass
    - apk update && apk add mariadb-client
    - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mariadb --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mariadb "$MYSQL_DATABASE"

  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
deploy:
  stage: deploy

  before_script:
    - chmod 400 $key
    - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mariadb --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" --host=mariadb "$MYSQL_DATABASE"

  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $key host "
      docker login -u username -p pass &&
      docker run -d -p 80:80 $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"
```

Dockerfile

```
    FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y default-mysql-client
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli


# Enable Apache rewrite module
RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY . /var/www/html

# Set the working directory

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Is this an issue with your CI/CD pipeline (you cannot deploy mysql) or is it an issue in your php code (mysql is up and running, but cannot connect to mysql)?

Comment: As per [ask] please provide code etc as text, not pictures

Comment: no, there is not problem with deployment, in build stage i got OK for mariadb but in deploy stage I got mariadb: not found

Comment: Your `deploy` job is a separate environment. You'll need to install `mariadb-client` again. You also need to define `services:` and `variables:` in that job as well (or move those configurations to the global defaults).

Comment: I added in deploy stage, but i got the following error, when i go to running container after deployment.
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)